# Ember Routing - Model hook not called on page refresh

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am trying to use nested routing to render a collection first. Once the collection is rendered, clicking on an item (using link-to) renders that particular item in the outlet. This all works fine so far.

I am having a problem where refreshing the page doesn't call the 'model' hook of my nested resource though.

From Ember's website at http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/:

> What happens if the user visits your application directly with a URL
>   that contains a dynamic segment? For example, they might reload the
>   page, or send the link to a friend, who clicks on it. At that point,
>   because we are starting the application up from scratch, the actual
>   JavaScript model object to display has been lost; all we have is the
>   ID from the URL.
>
> Luckily, Ember will extract any dynamic segments from the URL for you
>   and pass them as a hash to the model hook as the first argument

Here is my code:

```
Admin.Workqueues.App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('delinquencies', function () {
    this.resource('delinquency', {
      path: '/:id'
    });
  });
});

Admin.Workqueues.App.DelinquenciesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    // Does XHR here and fetches a collection of items to render.
    // Returns a promise
  }
});

Admin.Workqueues.App.DelinquencyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    debugger; // This doesn't get called
  }
});
```

So with this code, going to ***/delinquencies*** lists the entire collection. Clicking on an item opens a delinquency object at ***/delinquencies/3*** but now refreshing the page doesn't call the model hook of delinquency route.

I am not sure what I am missing. Any ideas? If it matters, I am using:

> Ember      : 1.2.0
>
> Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.f482da04
>
> Handlebars : 1.1.1

Comment: And you're hitting `delinquencies/7` or something like that?

Comment: Is there anything else in your delinquencies route that redirects, or is the code above the code currently being used?  Are you sure the DelinquencyRoute is actually included in the page and Ember isn't creating a dummy route for you?

Comment: I am not redirecting explicitly at all. For your second question on whether Ember is perhaps creating a dummy route, I don't think so because everything works fine by clicking on items in the collection.

Comment: Have you tried using the Ember inspector for Chrome or Firefox to inspect the route and make sure you're on the one you think it is?

Comment: @Rajat you don't need the route to `transitionTo` and `link-to`, in this example I'm linking to color without the color route, but if I were to refresh it'd have the same problem that yours does http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/315/edit

Comment: @kingpin2k so I am eager to know how to avoid that issue in your example? I mean reload the page with same content.? no way to do that?

Comment: Did you confirm that the route was in the page?  Like in my example's full screen (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/315) if you go to the console and type `App.ColorRoute` you get undefined, in your app's console if you type `Admin.Workqueues.App.DelinquencyRoute` is it defined?

Comment: @kingpin2k Yes, the route is available. Let me see if I can isolate my code and create a jsBin.

Comment: @kingpin2k there is an issue with you jsbin... I do not see how it can work in the first place... But I added a ColorRoute and the model method is called when you refresh the page. But the nested resources looks weird to me. You should have 2 separated routes.

Comment: Florian I intentionally removed the color route, hence why I said if you type it in the console you'd see undefined... I was showing Rajat how the app may appear to work, since the model hook is not called when you supply the model via the link-to, to show how you can build the app and think it's working, until you refresh the app and realize the app isn't grabbing the model.  Are there any other portions of it you don't understand?

Comment: This is a jsbin that would be a correct implementation of it: http://jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/404#/colors/1

Comment: @Rajat Any update here? Keen to get this question answered and/or closed if it's not an issue anymore with an explanation.

Comment: @JulianLeviston I haven't had the time to look into it again. I will try and get to it. If i cant, I will close it.

Comment: @Rajat apologies - if it's still current all good. You should possibly consider turning on logging transitions and internal transitions (LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL). It should help you track down what's taking place... take a look here: http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't define the resource as a child resource but as a separate one.

```
Admin.Workqueues.App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('delinquencies', function () {});
  this.resource('delinquency', { path: '/:delinquency_id' });
});
```

The reason your code works right now is because the link-to helper already provides the context so the model hook never gets called.

For the model hook in the DelinquencyRoute you should use something like this:

```
return this.store.find('delinquency', params.delinquency_id);
```

For more info, have a look at the guides and getting started tutorial:
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/ (the dynamic segments section answers your question)